# Creating TIN from UAV images or Google Earth images?

Tags: arcgis-desktop, tin, unmanned-aerial-vehicle

I'm starting using ArcGis and I would like to create a TIN from UAV images.

What are the steps that I have to follow?
I think:

- Mosaic the images, merge o join. (I have 40 aereal pictures in .JPG)
- Georeference the big joined picture with GPS points (I may have these points, but in other cases not).
- Do something else.
- Create the TIN or xyz cloud points to export to AutoCAD.

How can I do this?
Do I need other tools?

Answer (score 2):

Creating a TIN from UAV images is not a simple task. Prior to making the TIN, you need to design your flight plan so you have sufficient overlap in your flight. In order to build a TIN from imagery you must be able to extract a point cloud from the imagery, which must have stereo overlap. When you have the appropriate image collection, you can use software such as PhotoSynth or SimActive to extract a point cloud. When you have a point cloud of elevation points from the collected stereo images from the UAV you can create a TIN using mass points. The ortho process will be for visual, not TIN creation. An alternative to this process would be to generate contours from the stereo imagery in a stereo compilation software process; and then use the contours to create a TIN.

Comment: Thank you. However I don't know what may be the process. Supposed I had the images, I have to join them or not?

Comment: No, the joining of images will only give you a mosaic (single image for visual...pretty picture). You need to have a software (PhotoSynth or SimActive) that can make a point cloud from multiple images). I suggest you continue looking online at options. There are some pages dedicated to this process. I have seen someone put up a full workflow using a SenseFly UAV.

Answer (score 2):

There are many tools available that have the capability to create point clouds from images, including those from UAS systems.  These include:

- [PictoVear](http://www.stellacore.com/PictoVera/PictoVeraProductPage.html)
- [Pix4D](http://pix4d.com/)
- [Agisoft](http://www.agisoft.ru/)
- [SimActive](http://www.simactive.com/en)

The workflow for these are fairly straight forward and can easily create point clouds from overlapping images.

Comment: Thanks your answer. What abou erdas, what may I have to learn to do this? I read something like ArcGis is good to Create a tin, but I need other software to process the UAV imagery.

Answer (score 1):

You can look at the following resources:

http://www.int-arch-photogramm-remote-sens-spatial-inf-sci.net/XXXVIII-1-C22/69/2011/isprsarchives-XXXVIII-1-C22-69-2011.pdf

http://palentier.blogspot.com/2010/12/how-to-create-digital-elevation-model.html